# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE... from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am having trouble using parameters in a stored procedure. I believe I am not passing the parameters in correctly with the C#.

My code is roughly equivalent to:

```
public static string GetCustomer(string storedProcedure, string connectionString)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedure, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_table1", "table1");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_table2", "table2");

            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            IDataParameter[] temp = da.GetFillParameters();//returns 2 parameters
            da.Fill(dt);//Breaks here with the error below

            //Irrelevant code
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

*Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE tspos.get_customer; expected 2, got 0*

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_customer;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_customer
(
    IN _table1 VARCHAR(25),
    IN _table2 VARCHAR(25)
)
BEGIN
SET @t1 = CONCAT('SELECT a.*, b.* FROM ', _table1, ' a, ', _table2, ' b');
    PREPARE statement FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

The calls below work as expected, so I would imagine my issue is in the C#

```
CALL get_customer('table1', 'table2');
CALL get_customer('table3', 'table4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the name of your parameters should be prefixed with an `@` sign:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_table1", "table1");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_table2", "table2");
```

Also, make sure to set the command type appropriately:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(storedProcedure, con))
    {
        //Set command type
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_table1", "table1");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_table2", "table2");
        
        IDataParameter[] temp = da.GetFillParameters();//returns 2 parameters
        da.Fill(dt);

        //Irrelevant code
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. Same error.

Comment: @EricWarburton: What does the `da.GetFillParameters` method do?

Comment: From DbDataAdapter it says: Summary: Gets the parameters set by the user when executing an SQL SELECT statement. I was using it just to check that my parameters were set in da.

Comment: @EricWarburton: Sorry, I misread the name of the adapter (`da`). I thought it was some other class outside the scope of this method. I wonder if calling that is wiping out your parameters... I updated my answer so try that and see what happens.

Comment: @EricWarburton: I am now close to 100% sure your issue is the `@` signs as well as the command type not being set. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used the `MySqlDataAdapter`, it would be better to specify the parameters using the [`SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), also don't forget that you need to add one `@` before the parameter's name, something like this:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_table1", "table1");
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than `AddWithValue`.

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

As an another point you need to specify the type of your command to be stored procedure using a code like this:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```